# How to remove share point title in Embedded web part

Tags: html, web, sharepoint, web-parts

[image]I created a Page using Microsoft 365 admin credentials . Page contains staff directory details .

I wanted to publish this page on another page as a web part .

So I clicked on + symbol and gave embedded page option and added the link of the page ,I created as a web part .

But when it appears on the published page it’s having a header content share point and also has the user who has logged in .

On clicking the share point header it navigates to my home page where in , I cannot come back to this page again unless I give back button .

Can anyone say ways to remove the share point header from the web part .

i managed to remove the header sharepoint which appears in blue colour as it appears at the top.

Below is the orange color search icon which i wanted to hide as well. On hiding that from iframe, right side there appears a serach box it disappears.

Do we have any ways to hide the orange colour search icon or any ways to make it dummy?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Inspect the page and search for the css element. Get it's id/class

Step 2: With javascript prevent it from loading in the iframe.

As for the going back thing, you can style your iframe such that it appears over the button.

Comment: I have managed to hide the sharepoint key word from iframe ,here is the code i used :<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; border: solid 2px #555; width:594px; height:332px;">
<div style="overflow: hidden; margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -15px;">
</div>
<iframe src="url of the page " scrolling="no" style="height: 1500px; border: 0px none; width: 1509px; margin-top: -60px; margin-left: -14px; ">
</iframe>
</div>  .. I do not have access to answer my question